# Is there a way to solve the differential equation $y''+y'=\sec^2 (x)$ using undetermined coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My friend handed me a question from his exam, and was solving the following differential equation:
$$
y''+y=\sec^2(x)
$$

I solved it using variation of parameters:
$$
y=C_1 \cos(x) + C_2 \sin(x)+(\ln|\sec(x) + \tan(x)|)(\sin(x))-1
$$

I searched a little and couldn't find methods involving secants, cosecants nor tangents for undetermined coefficients. Is there a way to solve it using that technique? Or using variation of parameters is the only way to go?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335143/solving-y-4y-3-sin-2x-using-undetermined-coefficients

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231016/using-the-method-of-undetermined-coefficients-find-an-appropriate-particular-so

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206806/find-the-general-solution-given-the-complementary-solution-and-particular-soluti

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601694/find-general-and-particular-solution-for-y-y-e2x

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  Why do you think any of your links are relevant?

Comment: Very roughly speaking, the method of undetermined coefficient that you learn briefly only works for a set of functions that are closed under taking their derivatives. Like, polynomials and $\sin$ and $\cos$ and $e^x$. You take a derivative of any combination of them and it stays in the algebra  spanned by them. But you can clearly see $\tan$ or $\sec$ do not work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undetermined coefficients is just a special case of variation of parameters for differential equations with constant coefficients and inhomogenous terms of the form $x^n\exp(z x)$ ($n\in\mathbb N$ and $z\in \mathbb C$). This case is special because differentiating or integrating a term of that form always gives you more terms of that form with the same $z$. Thus it's easy to cancel out undesirable terms through choice of coefficients.

If the inhomogeneous term is not of that form, then this no longer works. The derivatives and antiderivatives have no guarantee to have functional forms with simple relations to each other. Further, even when you do find a relation among the relevant functional forms, the way to get the cancellations is often nonobvious. In this case, the presence of logs of trig functions seems very likely since $d_x^2\ln\cos x = \sec^2 x$. But it would take me a lot of trial and error with trig identities to come up with the key term $\sin x\ln(\sec x + \tan x) = \sin x \int \sec x dx$.

Answer (score 1):

*Or using variation of parameters is the only way to go?*
You can integrate the DEn directly:
$$y''+y=\sec^2(x)$$
$$\cos (x) y'' \color{red}{-\sin (x) y'+\sin (x) y'}+\cos (x) y=\dfrac 1 {\cos(x)}$$
$$(\cos (x )y')'+(\sin (x) y)'=\dfrac 1 {\cos(x)}$$
$$(\cos (x) y'+\sin (x) y)'=\dfrac 1 {\cos(x)}$$
Integrate to reduce the order.

You can also substitute $u=\cos x$:
$$y''+y=\sec^2(x)$$
$$(1-u^2)y''-uy'+y=\dfrac 1 {u^2}$$
$$((1-u^2)y')'+(uy)'=\dfrac 1 {u^2}$$
$$(1-u^2)y'+uy=-\dfrac 1 {u}+C_1$$